# `install-grub` claims that I have multiple partiton labels and that embedding is impossible

Tags: grub2

I am trying to get GRUB installed on my non-booting desktop computer, but I am encountering several errors. Other sources discussing these errors have ascribed them to either a lack of free disk space before the first partition (I have the requisite free space), or to a problem with `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (problem persists even after regenerating that file correctly).

I booted with a live USB and attempted to reinstall GRUB using the following commands, but I encounter an error that prevents it from working:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
$ sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: Attempting to install GRUB to a disk with multiple partition labels.  This is not supported yet..
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

However, `/dev/sda` appears to be formatted correctly for installing grub:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8d91017b

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 234440703 234438656 111.8G 83 Linux

$ blkid /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: UUID="84e9ff65-c4ba-42eb-8a6d-ebc703fae1f7" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8d91017b-01"
```

It has the standard 1 MiB free space at the beginning, and `/dev/sda1` is formatted correctly. I have tried using `grub-mkconfig` to rebuild the config file:

```
$ for f in proc sys dev dev/pts ; do sudo mount --bind /$f /mnt/$f ; done
$ sudo chroot /mnt
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-23-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

However, I still get the same error message when running `grub-install`, whether in or out of the `chroot` environment.

Booting the live USB in legacy mode, I get the same error; the only difference is the output of running `grub-mkconfig` in the `chroot` environment:

```
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-23-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sdc1
done
```

How can I get grub installed correctly?

Answer (score 35):

Nuke the gap between the boot sector and the first partition.

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX seek=1 count=2047
```

That's for if the first partition starts at sector 2048. Some start earlier, especially on drives that were partitioned by Windows. To be sure, run

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdX
```

before starting and check to see where the first partition starts. Use `count=S-1`, where S is the start of the first partition.

Comment: This worked for me. I'm trying to use BTRFS along a separate ext4 /boot partition. Thanks.

Comment: Note that this will trash a GPT layout. It's possible to recover from its backup though.

Comment: if you're using GPT then you need to wipe the BIOS BOOT PARTITION. Where that is depends on how you laid out your disk. I put mine after the GPT, between block 34 and 2047, assuming the first "real" partition begins at block 2048. Modifying the given command-line to use `seek=34 count=2014` works for me.

Comment: works perfectly!!!! grub should do it automatically though

Comment: Yeah, you'd think so, @brauliobo, but GRUB is total garbage. I don't even use it any more. These days, I use syslinux for mbr and systemd-boot for gpt.

Answer (score 3):

One can create a new partition where the GPT record is, then wipe it using `dd`. That way, only the MBR record will remain.

Assuming problem device is `/dev/sda`:

Create a new partition in the initial 1 MiB

```
$ parted /dev/sda
$ mkpart primary ext4 0MiB 1MiB
$ quit
```

Then, zero the newly created partition

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2
```

Then, delete the partition

```
$ parted /dev/sda
$ rm 2
$ quit
```

`grub-install` should now work as expected.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to justify what this code does, and why you believe it to be a solution.

Comment: Worked for me. Edited it for clarity

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar problem with the multiple partition labels, although i am quite sure that that is not the case.

```
sudo grub-install target=i386-pc /dev/sda --force
```

is what I used to get around this. Tacking on a `--force` is not a "recommended" solution, but I have had no issues so far =P

Comment: You mean `--target`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did that got it working again:

Used `gdisk` to convert the MBR partition to GPT, insert a partition into the empty space (type EF02 "BIOS Boot partition"), transposed its entry with my original partition, and flagged it as legacy BIOS bootable.

Then ran

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
$ sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

It then installed successfully, and I able to boot to my main drive.